# Mysql Load Data for existing column of a table

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, load-data-infile

Initially I have uploaded Using load Data Infile row is having like 100000 Im Using Ubuntu

Example:data

ToneCode....Artist...MovieName...Language

1....................Mj..........Null........... English

3....................AB..........Null........... English

4....................CD.........Null........... English

5....................EF..........Null........... English

But Now I have To update Column MovieName Starting From ToneCode 1 till 100000 row I’m having data in .csv file to update .
Please suggest how to upload the .Csv file for existing table with data

Comment: which language you using like php, java, C# etc.

Comment: Im Using Mysql server. Front End android im using.To Upload Im Using WorkBench To Upload data

Answer (score 2):

I think the fastest way to do this, using purely MySQL and no extra scripting, would be as follows:

- CREATE a temporary table, two columns ToneCode and MovieName same as in your target table
- load the data from your new CSV file into that using LOAD DATA INFILE
- UPDATE your target table using the INNER JOIN-like syntax that http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html describes:

  `UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price WHERE items.id=month.id;`

  this would “join” the two tables `items` and `month` (by using just the “comma-syntax” for an INNER JOIN) using the `id` column as the join criterion, and update the `items.price` column with the value of the `month.price` column.

Answer (score 0):

I Have found a solution as u Guys mentioned above

Soln: example

create table A(Id int primary Key, Name Varchar(20),Artist Varchar(20),MovieName Varchar(20));

Add all my 100000 row using

Load data infile '/Path/file.csv' into table tablename(A) fields terminated by ',' enclosed by'"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(Id,Name,Artist) here movie value is null

create temporary table TA(Id int primary Key,MovieName Varchar(20));

Uploaded data to temporary table TA
Load data infile '/Path/file.csv' into table tablename(A) fields terminated by ',' enclosed by'"'
lines terminated by '\n'(IDx,MovieName)

Now using join as u said

Update Tablename(TA),TableName(A) set A.MovieName=TA.MovieName Where A.Id=TA.Id